# Files and folders on Desktop automatically get renamed to "?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder, high-sierra, filesystem

I am currently running macos High Sierra 10.13.2 on a MacBook Air early-2014 and a weird thing has been happening for the last 2-3 days. When I turn on my mac, the files and folders on my desktop get renamed to `"?`.

For instance my folder named `Receipts` got renamed to `"?`. And even though I rename these files manually, the next time I start up, they get renamed back to `"?`.

The files in other directories seem to be unaffected.
Does anybody have any clue as to whats happening ?